# How to conditionally run jsf Validator on blur event with p:ajax?

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, primefaces

In my xhtml page I have inputText field with two Validators attached to it. Also there is ajax event "blur" attached for triggering validation when switching focus from a field. Here is the code:

```
<t:selectOneMenu id="locateRecordBy" value="#{personBean.locateRecordBy}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{personBean.locateRecordByItems}"/>
</t:selectOneMenu>

<t:inputText id="personName"
   value="#{personBean.name}"
   required="true" 
   requiredMessage="Name is required.">
        <p:ajax event="blur" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="nameerror" global="false" />
        <f:validator disabled="#{param['PersonForm:locateRecordBy'] == 'FEMALE'}" validatorId="com.myapp.validators.MalePersonValidator"/>
        <f:validator disabled="#{param['PersonForm:locateRecordBy'] == 'MALE'}" validatorId="com.myapp.validators.FemalePersonValidator"/>
</t:inputText>
```

So I'd like to validate personName against appropriate Validator depending of selecting item after focus is not anymore on the personName field. Any suggestions please, what should I change or add?

p.s. On form submit validation work very well.

Comment: I did not understand what it means, "*Validator depending of selecting item after focus is not anymore on the `personName` field*". Which library is `<t:inputText>` from? Is it from Tomahawk? Are those validators invoked/triggered and  work? Assuming you designated those validator classes with for instance, `@FacesValidaror(value="femalePersonValidator")` in which case, you just need to specify `validatorId="femalePersonValidator"`. A fully qualified class name is not needed. The `global` attribute associated with a `<p:ajax>` only needs to be taken into account, when you use `<p:ajaxStatus>`.

Comment: @Tiny If _female_ is selected from selectOneMeny then `FemalePersonValidator` is enabled and used for validating _name_ field while `MalePersonValidator` is disabled, also, if _male_ is selected from selectOneMeny then `MalePersonValidator` is enabled and used for validating _name_ field while `FemalePersonValidator` is disabled. This works very well when form is submitted.
Ajax validation of the field is the one that doesn't  work.
`t:inputText` is from Tomahawk.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found what was missing in my code. I added `locateRecordBy` componnent to be processed with ajax so instead of having this:

```
<p:ajax event="blur" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="nameerror" global="false" />
```

I have this:

```
<p:ajax event="blur" partialSubmit="true" process="@this, locateRecordBy" update="nameerror" global="false" />
```

Basically I forgot instruct JSF to process `locateRecordBy` and that's why `locateRecordBy` parameter was never present in the ajax request which caused both validators to be became disabled and validation of `personName` field to be skipped.